# I have a standard table with text inside. How do I vertical align this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates

Right now, the text seems not to be exactly vertical centered.
It seems that there is more top-padding than bottom-padding.

Although of course, there is no padding in the CSS. How do I make this completely vertical aligned?

Comment: have you used a css reset page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td valign = "middle">

In CSS:

vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
<table cellpadding="0">
```

Comment: I assumed you were using what @Levi put in his answer, can you verify. And if not please post code.